# Is it possible to rerun kubernetes job?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have the following Kubernetes Job configuration:

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: dbload
  creationTimestamp: 
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: dbload
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: dbload
        image: sdvl3prox001:7001/pbench/tdload
        command: ["/opt/pbench/loadTpcdsData.sh",  "qas0063", "dbc", "dbc", "1"]
      restartPolicy: Never
      imagePullSecrets: 
        - name: pbenchregkey
status: {}
```

When I do `kubectl create -f dbload-deployment.yml --record` the job and a pod are created, Docker container runs to completion and I get this status:

```
$ kubectl get job dbload
NAME      DESIRED   SUCCESSFUL   AGE
dbload    1         1            1h
$ kubectl get pods -a
NAME           READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
dbload-0mk0d   0/1       Completed   0          1h
```

This job is one time deal and I need to be able to rerun it. If I attempt to rerun it with `kubectl create` command I get this error

```
$ kubectl create -f dbload-deployment.yml --record
Error from server: error when creating "dbload-deployment.yml": jobs.batch "dbload" already exists
```

Of course I can do `kubectl delete job dbload` and then run `kubectl create` but I'm wondering if I can somehow re-awaken the job that already exists?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

No. There is definitely no way to rerun a kubernetes job.
You need to delete it first.

You can however create a new job based on existing job configuration that will be executed immediately:

`kubectl create job --from=job/dbload new-dbload -n <namespace>`

Comment: Those like me who need more details - this is two a step process. First delete your job with `kubectl delete job <job_name>` and then `kubectl apply -f <job_yml>`

Comment: It can be done in one step with `kubectl replace --force` - which will delete the job if it exists, and then (re-)create it unconditionally. See below.

Comment: @Caesar An example? Because I get `error: must specify one of -f and -k`

Comment: don't use `kubectl replace --force` by default. If you do and it fails (because it includes autogenerated fields), the original job will have been already deleted and you will not be able to rerun the command. Use `kubectl get -o yaml` first and at that point using `kubectl apply` is easier anyway.

Comment: @cohadar Can you approve my requested change, basically `kubectl create job --from=job/dbload new-dbload -n <namespace>` is probably what a lot of people need.

Comment: `--from=` only supports cronjob as a source. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/generated/kubectl_create/kubectl_create_job/#options

Answer (score 91):

Simulate a rerun by replacing the job with itself:

1. Backup your job:

- `kubectl get job "your-job" -o json > your-job.json`

2. Replace the job in place:

- `kubectl get job "your-job" -o json | kubectl replace --force -f -`

If you get errors due to auto-generated labels or selectors, you can delete or edit them with jq:

- `kubectl get job "your-job" -o json | jq 'del(.spec.selector)' | jq 'del(.spec.template.metadata.labels)' | kubectl replace --force -f -`

UPDATED with [Jeremy Huiskamp](https://serverfault.com/users/1763/jeremy-huiskamp)'s suggestion

Comment: Would strongly recommend saving a copy of the job json to a file first.  `kubectl replace` deletes the job before running into the errors recreating it.

Comment: Save the json first and then recreate!!

Comment: No need to save the json first if he still has the original job definition file?

Comment: F Santiago can you update the answer to incorporate @JeremyHuiskamp. edit queue is full

Comment: This works, but step 2 gives error about selectors. After removing those fields, you could simply do `kubectl apply -f your-job.yaml`.

Answer (score 48):

You can also avoid the error you mentioned by specifying

```
  generateName: dbload
```

instead of simply `name`

In that case, each job you submit with this yaml file will have a unique name that will look something like `dbloada1b2c`. Then you can decide whether you need to delete the old jobs, but you won't *have* to do it.

Here is a working yaml example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  generateName: netutils-
spec:
  parallelism: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: amouat/network-utils 
        name: netutil
      restartPolicy: Never
```

This is the output from `kubectl get job` after two `kubectl create -f example.yaml` commands:

```
NAME             COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
netutils-5bs2s   0/1           14s        14s
netutils-dsvfk   0/1           10s        10s
```

Comment: I believe generateName only applies to kind=pod and NOT job.

Comment: No, it's a standard part of ObjectMeta and applies to both pod and job:
[k8s reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/resources-reference/v1.7/#objectmeta-v1-meta). I've been using it all the time, it's core to what I'm doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for this dodge. Just for documentation this does only work with `kubectl create`

Comment: disagree. Tried to do this right now and it causes error "resource name may not be empty".

Comment: @rudolfdobias I suspect that the error you see is related to something different, not Job.metadata.name parameter. I've been using that for years, and it works both on GKE and AKS. Would you be able to share you yaml config?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, I get "resource name may not be empty
". Can you provide a full working k8s yaml snippet with generateName ?

Comment: @BalintBako, I have added an example yaml that I have just tested on GKE. (Added to my original answer, as there seems to be no way to add a block of code in the comment.) My guess is that you're omitting `name` attribute in `spec.containers`. Note that `generateName` attribute belongs to `metadata`.

Comment: thx @vp124, this is how I tried and doesn't work on every platform that runs k8s. It might be version dependent, I will check that.

Comment: Are you creating your job with `kubectl create` or `kubectl apply`? The latter will not work, as per this reference: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44501. So you have to do `kubectl create`.

I have also just tried on Azure, it works there as well. 

`kubectl version` shows `v1.15.10` on AKS and `v1.14.10-gke.27` ok GKE, but like I said, I've been doing this for quite a while, so it worked on earlier versions, too.

Comment: This is a better solution than delete/re-create in my usecase. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

As an improvement on @F. Santiago's idea, you can simply use the value stored at the annotation `"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration"` that holds the initial applied configuration without any auto generated field:

```
kubectl get job <jobname> -o json | \
jq -r '.metadata.annotations."kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration"' | \
kubectl replace --save-config --force -f -
```

Note: for `kubectl replace`, remember to pass `--save-config` so it updates the annotation field with the last config applied.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to run a job that completed but you can simulat a rerun by doing the following

1. Get yaml file of the existing job:

   ```
   kubectl get job <job_name> -o yaml > <job_name>.yaml
   ```
2. Delete the existing job:

   ```
   kubectl delete job <job_name>
   ```
3. Run the job again:

   ```
   kubectl apply -f <job_name>.yaml
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Marcelo's idea I made it work with the following, without any processing of the template:

```
kubectl get job <job-name> -o custom-columns=:metadata.annotations.kubectl\.kubernetes\.io/last-applied-configuration > job.json
kubectl delete -f job.json
kubectl apply -f job.json
```

Please note the escaped dots (`\.`) in the annotation name: `kubectl\.kubernetes\.io/last-applied-configuration`. Without it, it returns `<none>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented F. Santiago's method using a kubectl plugin.  I have these two files in my PATH [1] so that kubectl picks it up.

Now issuing `kubectl replacejob [job name]` looks like this:

```
[w] eddie@eddie ~ $ kubectl replacejob my_job_name
Writing out backup file: my_job_name.bak.json
job.batch "my_job_name" deleted
job.batch/my_job_name replaced
```

[1] Files to make the plugin work:

`kubectl-replacejob.cmd`: Simple wrapper to call python with the same args

```
@echo off

pushd . 
cd %~dp0
python kubectl-replacejob.py %*
popd
```

`kubectl-replacejob.py`: Does the 'hard' work of replacement.

```
import sys
import subprocess
import json
import io

if len( sys.argv ) < 2:
    print("Error: please specify the job you wish to replace.")
    sys.exit(-1)

job_name = sys.argv[1]

# Fetch the job as json
job_as_json_text = subprocess.check_output(f'kubectl get job {job_name} -o json', shell=True).decode()
job_as_json = json.loads(job_as_json_text)

# Save out a backup
backup_file = f'{job_name}.bak.json'
print(f"Writing out backup file: {backup_file}")
with open(backup_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(job_as_json_text)

# Remove references to controller uid that borks replace
def remove_key_if_present(obj, *keys):
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        key = keys[i]
        if key in obj:
            if i == len(keys)-1:
                del obj[key]
            else:
                obj = obj[key]
        else:
            print(f"WARNING: Failed to remove {'.'.join(keys)}: failed finding key at {key}!")
            return 


remove_key_if_present(job_as_json, 'spec', 'selector', 'matchLabels', 'controller-uid')
remove_key_if_present(job_as_json, 'spec', 'template', 'metadata', 'labels', 'controller-uid')
job_as_json_text = json.dumps(job_as_json)

# Pretty print for testing
#print(json.dumps(job_as_json, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

# Issue the replace
subprocess.run(f'kubectl replace --force -f -', shell=True, input=job_as_json_text.encode())
```

Answer (score 0):

On the subject of deleting a `Job` before you can run it again, as [the accepted answer](https://serverfault.com/a/846293/90074) states, note that you can now also set up a `Job` to automatically clean itself after completion with [`.spec.ttlSecondsAfterFinished`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/ttlafterfinished/)